# opencv-python namedWindow() can't resize window

Tags: opencv, python

I am using `namedWindow()` function in my code to resize the image's window. The mouse cursor showing i can resize the windows, but it actually can't. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('/home/jeff/Downloads/iphone.png', 1)
cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Please assist. Thanks.

Comment: Question solved. After restarting the machine, image is resizeable.

Answer (score 1):

Replace code line `cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)` with following:

```
cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
```

Comment: How would this solve the issue? With `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` "the user cannot resize the window, the size is constrainted by the image displayed." ([see documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ggabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3acf621ace7a54954cbac01df27e47228f)).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug (at least in v3.2.0) that the resizing does not work if the image is bigger than the screen resolution. See the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13995).